# SAS : how to import a csv file with datetime variable where the data in different format between mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss and dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: csv, datetime, import, sas

How to import a csv dataset into SAS properly. The main problem is the records under the variable date_time is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm and mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss? How to use SAS informat to corrrect this problem?

Comment: Thank you Tom, it still does not work.I imported a csv file which contains a variable date_time 
Type – Numeric
Length – 8
Format DATETIME.Informat ANYDTDM40. 

Eg. Date_time variable

csv    After import
13/01/2017 12:30:00   13JAN17:12:30:00
13/01/2017 17:30:00  13JAN17:17:30:00
06/04/2019 04:30:00  04JUN19:04:30:00
12/11/2019 05:00:00  11DEC19:05:00:00

After import the date_time is a numeric type, how can I standardise it into a single format dd/mm/yyyy:hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: If you READ the field from the CSV file using the ANYDTDM informat then you already have a DATETIME value.  If you just want to change how it is DISPLAYED then use a different FORMAT with the variable.  But why does it matter which style of displaying the datetime values you use?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Tom. The main thing is the data format input differently ;say the first record is 31/05/2019 12:30:00 displayed as 31May2019:12:30:00 but next record is 06/01/2019 04:30:00 displayed as 01JUN19:04:30:00 due to the dataset was input by different people. Some use American and some use Australia format. Therefore, there is an ambiguity when SAS reads it. How do I clean the data which consists of 400K records where the date/time are input differently but in sequential.

Comment: Re-read the first two paragraphs of my answer.  You have to write your own data step to read the file so SAS does not read the text with the ANYDTDTM informat. That way the actual value is preserved.  Then you need to make your own decisions on each observation about which date style it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV file with your own data step so that you can preserve the text of the field by reading it as a character variable.

Then to properly convert ambiguous string like 10/12/2021 you will need some other way to learn whether that observation should use date style of MDY or DMY.  Perhaps you know what country the data is from? Or you have some other date value on the record that might help.  For example if you know the dates for this record should be after Nov 2021 then you can deduce that 10/12/2021 means the tenth of December.

Once you know which style to use for a particular observation use the appropriate INFORMAT to read the date.  So if you read the text into DATESTRING and you calculated a variable named DATESTYLE that tells which type of date style to use for this observations then add this snippet of code to the data step to convert the string into a datetime value.

```
if datestyle='MDY' then do;
   datetime=dhms(input(scan(datestring,1,' '),mmddyy10.),0,0
                .input(scan(datestring,2,' '),time8.))
   ;
end;
else do;
   datetime=dhms(input(scan(datestring,1,' '),ddmmyy10.),0,0
                .input(scan(datestring,2,' '),time8.))
   ;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. But it still doesn't work.